# Sidebar menu should NOT get collapse/close when i click outside the body

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Actually I am facing an issue where I don't want the menu of my sidebar menu to get closed when I click anywhere outside. right now it gets collapsed/closed when I click anywhere.

This is my method which senses when user clicks anywhere outside the body.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class WatchClickOutside extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('in comp mount');
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('in comp unmount');

        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        let { container } = this.refs;
        const { onClickOutside } = this.props;

        const { target } = event;
        if (typeof onClickOutside !== 'function') {
            console.log(' in if of onclickoutside');
            return;
        }

        if (target !== container && !container.contains(target)) {
            console.log('clicked outside - fire callback');
            onClickOutside(event); // clicked outside - fire callback
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="container">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default WatchClickOutside;
```

And this is the code where I render the sidebar.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WatchClickOutside from './watch-outside';


class Sidebar extends Component {

  handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    **//WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO RESTRICT THE CLOSE OF SIDEBAR ONCLICK**
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WatchClickOutside onClickOutside={this.handleClickOutside}>
          <Nav vertical className="sidebar">
            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar className="manage-profile">
              <DropdownToggle nav caret className="nav-link" aria-hidden="true">
     SIDEBAR
      </DropdownToggle>
     <DropdownMenu>
                **//DROPDOWN MENU HERE**
       </DropdownMenu>
          </Nav>
       </UncontrolledDropdown>
        </WatchClickOutside>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say how your custom component handles click, but there is a few things you could try.

1:

```
e.preventDefault()
e.stopPropagation()
```

inside of `handleClickOutside`

2:

Handling `mouseDown` instead of `click` event and calling the functions above could also help.

3:

Handling events from (1) and (2) inside of `Nav` instead of wrapping into parent component listening to body. Once clicks came to body they already bubble from the origin and so probably got handled by  `Nav` by closing sidebar. The bottom line is that you wanna handle events closer to their initial source.

I would say you should start with (3) first.